# cleanup bat command output in Jenkins Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, wmic

How to cleanup output of a bat command in pipeline script on Jenkins

Following is the pipeline script I have used.

```
Drive_list = bat (  label: 'Get Drive List',
                    returnStdout: true,
                    script: 'wmic logicaldisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceID'
                    ).trim()
```

Drive_list  now contains following.

```
{D:\Jenkins\workspace\test>wmic logicaldisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceID 
    DeviceID  

    C:        

    D:}
```

What should be done for extracting a list `{'C:','D:'}`

I have tried creating a list  by tokenizing Drive_list using `c_list = Drive_list.tokenize('\r\n')`, and now c_list is

`{[D:\Jenkins\workspace\test>wmic logicaldisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceID , DeviceID  , , C:        , , D:]}`

To clean up `c_list` I have tried following
 `c_list.removeAll{ it.contains('DeviceID')`  resulted in

`{[DeviceID  , , C:        , , D:]}` which only removed first line, but still has others adding to this the drive IDs have some white characters which I am unable to remove.

Comment: Have you tried stuff like `@echo off` in the script section? Maybe you can suppress the table headers via the `wmic /format` options?

Comment: @DominikGebhart didn't try it before, but I tried it now and  none of them worked. Figured out that the issue is with encoding. Adding encoding "UTF-16LE" option to pipeline script fixed it

Comment: Great, don't forget to mark your solution as resolved, so others can quickly find it and it wont show for filters with unresolved questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for none of the groovy methods are working because of encoding, modifying pipeline script by adding encoding option "UTF-16LE" worked.

```
Drive_list = bat (  label: 'Get Drive List',
                    returnStdout: true,
                    encoding  : "UTF-16LE",
                    script: 'wmic logicaldisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceID'
                    ).trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the groovy(java) native method to get root drives:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots()

```
File[] Drive_list = File.listRoots()
```

Comment: This could work, but it would require permissions from admin of Jenkins to run listRoots. Which might not go through, since it introduces a security vulnerability